# Cannot find element using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests

I am trying to navigate to "https://developers.google.com/".

I then click a link by the xpath and redirect to another page.

Everything works as far as finding elements and clicking links on the first page.

But I cannot seem to find the elements I want to look for after I go to the new page.

The redirected page is "https://cloud.withgoogle.com/next18/sf/?utm_source=devsite&utm_medium=hpp&utm_campaign=cloudnext_april18"

This is checking if text is equal.

```
   confirmText("Imagine", "//*[@id=\"main\"]/span/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h3");

    public static void confirmText(String text, String xpath) {
    System.out.println("Trying to confirm that given string is equal to the text on page.");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    System.out.println("Test case: " + text);
    System.out.println("Result: " + element.getText());
    if (element.getText() == text) {
        System.out.println("\nEquals.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("\nDoes not equals.");
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");
}
```

This is sending keys.

```
    public static void sendKeys() {
    WebElement firstname = driver.findElement(By.id("firstName"));
    firstname.sendKeys("John");
    WebElement lastname = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"lastName\"]"));
    lastname.sendKeys("Doe");
    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"email\"]"));
    email.sendKeys("johndoe@gmail.com");
    WebElement jobtitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"jobTitle\"]"));
    jobtitle.sendKeys("Software Engineer");
    WebElement company = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"company\"]"));
    company.sendKeys("ABCD");
}
```

The error is

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="main"]/span/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h3"}
```

Comment: Immediately after your driver declaration, add this line `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` It would work for you.

Comment: I then click a link by the xpath  ? which link you are trying to click , please provide the manual steps.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first page actually waits to finish loading before the script starts. If you navigate away form the page then you will need to manually wait. Without waiting, the script will continue to the next command immediately after clicking the link that changes the page, and since the page is not loaded yet you will not find the element. This gives the error.

The simplest way to wait is by using "WebDriverWait"

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id(>someid>)));
```

There are more simple examples here:
http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/wait-commands/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this xpath using for imagine and put some wait as @chris mentioned

```
//div//h3[contains(text(),'Imagine')]
```

Answer (score 0):

JavascriptExecutor can be used to get the value of an element,

Refer code,

```
confirmText("Imagine", "//*[@id=\"main\"]/span/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/h3");

public static void confirmText(String text, String xpath) {
System.out.println("Trying to confirm that given string is equal to the text on page.");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver; 
System.out.println("Test case: " + text);
System.out.println("Result: " + executor.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element););
if (text.equals(executor.executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;", element))) {
    System.out.println("\nEquals.");
}
else {
    System.out.println("\nDoes not equals.");
}
System.out.println("\n\n");}
```